# How to debounce search function in this React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I have a component which gets a list of employees as a prop. I've also created an input element for filtering the list by string.
I moved filtering logic into a function which expects a list of data and a search value so it could return filtered list.

I want to add lodash debounce to search input, so whenever user types something, it would wait 1 second and filter the list out.

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from "lodash"

import { IEmployee } from '../../../store/EmployeesStore/reducer'

import AddEmployee from '../AddEmployee/AddEmployee';
import EmployeeItem from './EmployeeItem/EmployeeItem';

import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

export interface EmployeeProps {
  employees: IEmployee[];
}

class EmployeeList extends React.Component<EmployeeProps> {
  state = {
    searchValue: ''
  };

//function which returns filtered list
  filterList = (employeesList: IEmployee[], searchValue: string) => { 

    return employeesList.filter((item: any) => {
      const fullName = `${item.firstName}${item.lastName}`.toLowerCase();
      const reversedFullName = `${item.lastName}${item.firstName}`.toLowerCase();
      const trimmedSearchValue = searchValue
        .replace(/\s+/g, '')
        .toLowerCase();
      return (
        fullName.includes(trimmedSearchValue) ||
        reversedFullName.includes(trimmedSearchValue)
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    // saving filtered list data in filteredList variable
    let filteredList = this.filterList(this.props.employees, this.state.searchValue)
      
    return (
      <>
        <AddEmployee />
        <TextField
          style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}
          size="medium"
          id="input-with-icon-textfield"
          variant="outlined"
          value={this.state.searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ searchValue: e.target.value })}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
        />
        <div>
          <ul
            style={{
              margin: '0px',
              padding: '0px',
              listStyle: 'none',
              display: 'flex',
              flexWrap: 'wrap',
            }}
          >
            {filteredList.map((employee) => {
              return <EmployeeItem key={employee.id} {...employee} />;
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default EmployeeList;
```

Where should I add the _.debounce function and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only showing the relevant changes :-

```
constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    searchValue: ''
  };
this.debouncedHandler = _.debounce(this.handleChange.bind(this),1000);
}
```

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: e.target.value })};
}
```

```
        <TextField
          style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}
          size="medium"
          id="input-with-icon-textfield"
          variant="outlined"
          value={this.state.searchValue}
          onChange={this.debouncedHandler}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
        />
```

**Explanation** : We are calling the `debouncedHandler` repeatedly via `onChange` so we need to ensure that `handleChange` only gets triggered once that burst of `1000`ms is over and no call to `debouncedHandler` happened within this duration. If another call to `debouncedHandler` happens within that burst interval a new burst interval starts.

From your component's perspective, we are delaying the execution of our main logic which is inside `handleChange` by `1000`ms everytime unless the user doesn't enter any other character in the `TextField` component within that `1000ms`, once that `1000`ms are over, the `setState` will get triggered to state the state ---> meaning a re-render -----> meaning new filteredList and it's display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling your filterList function in return statement, instead of that it must be called on onChange of TextField.

Something like this:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: e.target.value })};
    const debouncedCall = _.debounce(() => this.filterList(this.props.employees, e.target.value), 1000);
    debouncedCall();    
}

//Rest of your code

render() {
   <TextField
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        ...other attributes
   />
}
```